# A point-wise separation Hahn-Banach theorem in C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. We denote  $K(H)$ by the space of compact operators on $H$ which is a two sided ideal in $B(H)$.

Let $E$ be a norm closed convex subset of positive operators in $K(H)$ and let $a$ be a non-zero positive compact operator  where $a\notin E$.

Q: Is there any vector $\zeta\in H$ which separates $a$ and $E$, I mean there is a a positive number $\lambda$ such that for all $x\in E$
$$ \langle x\zeta,\zeta\rangle\leq \lambda< \langle a\zeta,\zeta\rangle$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2 \times 2$ counterexample, $E = \left\{\left[\matrix{\lambda& 0\cr 0&\lambda}\right]: \lambda \geq 0\right\}$ and $A = \left[\matrix{1&1\cr 1&1}\right]$. Then for any nonzero $\zeta$ we have $\{\langle B\zeta,\zeta\rangle: B \in E\} = [0,\infty)$, so no $\zeta$ can separate.

The general idea is that you can separate $E$ and $a$ with a bounded linear functional on $K(H)$, i.e., tracing against some trace class operator, but you can't expect to do it with a single vector.

Comment: As a coda to the above answer: what you need for the argument to work is that the set be closed not just for  the norm but in the so-called weak operator topology (even in the strong operator topology).

Comment: Dear Nik, You mean $E$ and $a$ can be  separated by a **positive** trace class operator?

Comment: @oeiras: no, we're talking about subsets of $K(H)$, not $B(H)$. The weak* topology isn't relevant.

Comment: @AliBagheri: no way. If $E$ is a cone, then tracing against any positive operator will yield either $\{0\}$ or $[0,\infty)$. Getting $\{0\}$ is too much to ask for.

Comment: @NikWeaver  The spaces $K(H)$ and the finite dimensional operators form a dual pair in the natural way and so we can apply the Hahn-Banach theorem to this situation.

Comment: @oeiras: oh, did you mean that you can achieve separation with a single vector if you're WOT closed, but only with a trace class operator if you're norm closed? I don't think so --- you only get separation by tracing against a finite rank operator, not taking inner products against a single vector (or pair or vectors).

Comment: No. I was just pointing out that for any separation result of this type, the norm topology would not be appropriate---the only candidate could be the WOT.